# Action bar custom view is not positioning right

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to customize the action bar. What i wanted is this [image]

and what i am getting is this [image]

Text is not right in the center

this is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="THE WORD"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/actionbar_logo"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and in code

```
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext).inflate(R.layout.action_custom_view, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

How can i achieved that.
Thanks.

Comment: But text is in the center.

Comment: title is left-aligned on android ;) . ux pattern/guide

Comment: this not a title. I customize the action bar.
@SpringBreaker, title is not in the center. there is a difference in both snapshots.

Comment: @FIXI: You want the `TextView` in the horizontal center of the device or center in between `Menu` and right `ImageView` ?

Comment: yeah bro, I wanted exactly this :)

Comment: Please, use the native navigation drawer icon and align the title to the left. Actions should be on the right in the action bar. Please follow the android design guidelines and take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html Also, you might want to want to search on YouTube for Android Design in Action. Some really helpful design guidelines explained there.

Comment: Also note that relative layout for custom action bars are a tricky when it comes to sizing properly. Maybe match parent will help as well

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it?